# No imprime por pantalla las variables del ciclo

Tags: sql, tsql

No logro entender Por qué no imprime el resultado de cada ciclo.

```sql
declare @fecha_inicio as datetime
declare @fecha_fin as datetime
set @fecha_inicio = '20230401'
set @fecha_inicio = '20230405'

while (@fecha_inicio <= @fecha_fin)
    begin
        print(@fecha_inicio)
        set @fecha_inicio = DATEADD(DAY,1,@fecha_inicio)
        print(@fecha_inicio)
    end
```

Error: No estoy recibiendo ningún tipo de error.

> Commands completed successfully.

> Completion time: 2023-04-13T12:20:44.1186268-04:00

Resultado que espero:

Imprimir por pantalla todas las fechas entre el rango establecido
desde el día 1 hasta el dí 15 del mes de abril de 2023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

está mal tu código, asignaste valor dos veces la @fecha_inicio y nunca asignaste valor @fecha_fin

con el siguiente código funcionará

````
declare @fecha_inicio as datetime
declare @fecha_fin as datetime
set @fecha_inicio = '20230401'
set @fecha_fin = '20230405'

while (@fecha_inicio <= @fecha_fin)
    begin
        print(@fecha_inicio)
        set @fecha_inicio = DATEADD(DAY,1,@fecha_inicio)
        print(@fecha_inicio)
    end
```
````

Comment: Gracias no me di cuenta de la otra variable, estaba bloqueado. En Tsql no puedes colocar algo como puntos de interrupcion para depurar o ver que trae ciertos valores en timepo de ejecucion?

Comment: En el SQL Server Management Studio hay una opción para depurar, pero, tienes que configurarla también en el Servidor de SQL, 
personalmente hago un "select" del valor que quiero ver y después uso la sentencia "return" para detener la ejecución